# File.delete() is not actual

Tags: java, file

I want to delete a Folder with its content. If the file-structure is the following:

```
 TestFolder
    -Folder1
        --File1
    -Folder2
        --File2
        --File3
```

The Array should contain the Files in the order: {Folder1,Folder2,File1,Folder3,File2,File3}, by using the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;

class Folder{
    private int filesCount = 0;
    private File[] files;
    private int counter = 0;

    private void getFilesArray() throws IOException{
        paths = new String[countFiles(path)];
        thisFolder(path);
    }

    private void countFiles(File folder) throws IOException{
        File[] content = (new File(folder)).listFiles();
        for (File file:content){    
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                countFiles(file);
            }
            filesCount++;
        }
    }

    private void thisFolder(File folder) throws IOException{
        if (folder.exists()){
            File[] content = file.listFiles();
            for (File file:content){
                files[counter] = file;
                counter++;
                if (file.isDirectory()){
                    thisFolder(file);
                }
            }
        }else{
            throw new IOException("Folder was deleted while it was still opened:    "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

I want to delete the content of the Folder by using the File[]-Array:

```
public boolean delete(){
    for (int count = filesCount-1; count >= 0;count--){
        if(files[count].exists()){
            if(files[count].delete()==false){
                System.out.println("Failed to delete    "+files[count]);
                for (String temp:files[count].list())
                    System.out.println("    remaining content   "+temp);
                return false;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Properly deleted    "+files[count].getAbsolutePathPath());
            }
        }
    }
    if (folder.delete()){
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println(2);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need the File[]-Array in multiple further methods and actually want the Folder-object I´m creating to contain the -perhaps old- content of the moment I´m creating it. The delete method shall return false if not worked. Errorhandling is in a different class. Now the issue:

It deletes all Files propery by the first run and every Folder which was empty before I ran the program, but it Fails to delete the folders which had content before I ran the program, even if they´re empty now.

Here the debug output (first run):

```
//Properly deleted        Folder2\File3.txt
//Properly deleted        Folder2\File2.txt
//Failed to delete        Folder2
//  remaining content       File2.txt
//  remaining content       File3.txt
//program aborted
```

Here the debug output (second run):

```
//Properly deleted        Folder2
//Properly deleted        Folder1\File1.txt
//Failed to delete        Folder1
//  remaining content       File1.txt
//program aborted
```

Here the debug output (third run):

```
//Properly deleted        Folder1
//Properly deleted        TestFolder
//program completed
```

The directory-of course- is only for the program to test, so I´m sure there are no other (hidden) files in it. There is -for the testing-also no different program or method using the folders content, so even if it can be different when I´ll use the code for what I programmt it, for this test I´m absolutly sure that the File[]-Array is actual! I´ve even testsed the recursively method from comment below, but still get the same problem, even if the debug output is a bit different, becouse the order I visit Files and Folders is different.
Is there any trick to make the file actual again? Maybe a command like File.update();

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your `sleep` call will never accomplish anything. Nothing will change from when you start sleeping to when you finish. Have you thought about approaching this problem recursively? I think any way you try to write this iteratively, it will be very confusing, even if correct.

Comment: @hexaflexagonal Thats how I get the File[]-Array (recursively). But I use the Method to get the file Array for multiple tasks and whenever I want to use the method to delete the folder, I already have the File[]-Array. So I thought it would be efficient to use it.

Comment: OP has already done the recursive part, in assembling the array of `File` objects.  The iterative approach here seems correct to me, once this array is available. @hexaflexagonal

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'd argue the whole thing should be done recursively. Joseph Larson's answer captures the basic structure of how I believe this should be done, even though in a real application more checks and error handling should be included.

Comment: @hexaflexagonal Yes, but the recursive approach will still issue the same calls to the `delete` method, in the same order.  We still don't know why Taylor's original code doesn't work; and Joseph Larson's answer won't help.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Good point.

Comment: Actually, it's not the exact same order; but it's a similar order.  Joseph's code visits each directory in the opposite order from Taylor's code, but it still does each file _before_ the directory that contains it, which is the key point with regard to the ordering.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No, recursive works because the file order in OPs array is flawed because it has the folders before their content (`Folder1,Folder2,File1,`needs to be `File1,Folder2,...`) while the recursive code correctly deletes them after their content (`file.listFiles()`, delete each, then `file.delete()` on the folder)

Comment: Taylor, did you consider using the `delete` method of the `Files` class (in the `nio` package)?  It actually throws an exception when it fails to delete a file or a directory.  If you examine the exception, you might be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: @zapl Did you read Taylor's code?  It traverses the array in reverse order.

Comment: *"but it Fails to delete the folders which had content before I ran the program, even if they´re empty now"* - Are you sure there are no hidden files in it?

Comment: Taylor, to address MadProgrammer's second comment under Joseph's answer, maybe you can show us the code that generates the array.

Comment: Yes, Im sure that the folder is empty.  / /    How exactly do I use the "delete method of the Files class"? / / Joseph Larsons code, however, couses the same bug, so I guess when I want to delete a folder, the File-object has still unactual information about its content. But even if I create a new File only for deleting -> the bug remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out, why the delete() method didn´t worked out! In the method to count the size of the folder (so 0mB for this) I opened a fileChannel and forgot to close it properly. It seems as that coused the issue. Now that I added the close() command it works just fine... What a stupid mistake ^^ 
Thanks to anyone who tryed on helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

You're off track. First, drop the sleep. It's not necessary.

Next, how sure are you that you're deleting in the proper order? I personally wouldn't delete it the way you're doing it. I'd make a recursive method that deletes the file and it's contents.

```
void deleteMe(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
         for (File subfile: file.listFiles) {
             deleteMe(subfile);
         }
    }
    file.delete();
}
```

For debugging your code above, before the call to delete, I might add a debug like:

```
System.out.printf("File: %s. Number of subfiles: %d\n", file.getName(), file.listFiles().length).
```

(Something like that.)

Just to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Not sure how this will fix the problem.  It's issuing the exact same calls to `File.delete` in a similar order.  (And you want to add parentheses after `listFiles`).

Comment: I don't trust his input list. It's a REALLY weird way to do a delete. If he really wants to delete the folder with the contents, he should write a method that actually does so recursively to ensure it really is empty.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem What happens if, in the OPs code `files[count]` is a directory and that directory is not empty - it will fail - which is "possibly" the likely cause to their issue - Jospeh's example will first remove all the files from the directory (recursively) before attempting to delete it

Comment: Yes, maybe in isolation the recursive approach would be better; but when Taylor has already written the method to turn the tree into an array, for use in other places in the application, it makes sense to re-use it.

Comment: Tryed this one, but the problem still remains. The first time I execute the program it deletes File1, File2 and File3 (Filesystem above). The second time Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3 :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer Taylor's code has already addressed that.  Each directory's contents appears in the array, after the directory itself.  So assuming there are no files missing from the array, traversing the array backwards will do the right thing.  Of course, if there are files missing from the array, all bets are off.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem *"So assuming there are no files missing from the array"* which would be my assumption, that their are still files contained in the directories (hidden or otherwise) - but since we don't know how and when the original list is generated, it's difficult to know

Comment: Regardless of the underlying issue (which I expect lies outside of the code presented), I think the iterative approach is far more likely to introduce errors (it's completely dependent on the caller structuring the input in a very precise way) and suggests premature optimization. I would use the recursive approach as a starting point instead unless you can measure a non-negligible performance impact. But I won't say anymore on the topic since it's tangential.

Comment: Then print out more debug information. For the directory that won't delete, print out not just the name, but the contents from listFiles(). There's a REASON it won't delete, and it's not because you need to pause.

Comment: @Joseph Larson, hve edited my question with some information